# Understanding Google Earth Pro ruler tool algorithms?

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-pro, geoid, heading

When using Google Earth Pro ruler (Tools / Ruler or by clicking on the "ruler" icon), the ruler tool tells us the heading from one point to another which is not the same as that obtained by Karney's algorithm (a few tenths of degrees for long distances).

Could taking the geoid into account explain this difference?

Are there any algorithms to calculate the heading with the same precision as Google Earth Pro?